# Ember - Force https with heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, ember.js, https

I've made a ember app deployed on `heroku`. Heroku provides me an `ssl certificat` so https `is working` on my website.

I want to force visitors to uses https. I've found some answer telling to do-it in a client side, but since the client can modify JS he will be able to pass-by the force https.

I'm thinking about doing it in a `beforeModel` of the ember app.
What's the `best approach` ? 
Many thanks

Comment: What are you using to serve the ember app?

Comment: The ember buildpack provided by heroku

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So guys, 
I was able to force **HTTPS** by adding a `static.json` in my root folder of the app.

And in this **static.json** just add

```
{
  "https_only": true
}
```

commit, push to heroku and that's it !